ASP.NET adding style for attributes himself
_Layout.cshtml contains elements that have the same classes applied, but ASP generates an additional attribute and defines additional styles for this attribute, while it does not do this for another block, how to get rid of this.
Block of code with a problem:
<form asp-controller="Template" asp-action="Search" method="get" class="flex-grow-1 ms-4 me-4">
        <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="searchQuery" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@localizer["Search"]</button>
        </div>
</form>

_Layout.cshtml
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localizer

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="light">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - CourseProject</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/CourseProject.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.7.1/css/all.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center p-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <button id="theme-toggle" class="btn btn-secondary">@localizer["SwitchTheme"]</button>
            <div class="language-switcher">
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ChangeLanguage" asp-route-culture="en" class="btn btn-link">@localizer["English"]</a>
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ChangeLanguage" asp-route-culture="ru" class="btn btn-link">@localizer["Russian"]</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form asp-controller="Template" asp-action="Search" method="get" class="flex-grow-1 ms-4 me-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="searchQuery" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@localizer["Search"]</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="dropdown">
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="userDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    @User.Identity.Name
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Index">@localizer["Profile"]</a></li>
                    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">@localizer["AdminPanel"]</a></li>
                    }
                    <li>
                        <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">@localizer["Logout"]</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
            else
            {
                <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2">@localizer["Login"]</a>
                <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" class="btn btn-primary">@localizer["Register"]</a>
            }
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - CourseProject
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script>
        const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');
        const htmlElement = document.documentElement;

        const savedTheme = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('theme='))?.split('=')[1];
        if (savedTheme) {
            htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', savedTheme);
        } else {
            const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
            htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', prefersDarkScheme ? 'dark' : 'light');
        }

        themeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const currentTheme = htmlElement.getAttribute('data-bs-theme');
            const newTheme = currentTheme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
            htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', newTheme);
            document.cookie = `theme=${newTheme}; path=/; max-age=31536000`;
        });
    </script>


    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>



Other element, but without a problem


This could be the result of a new feature called CSS isolation. See here: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/355/css-isolation-in-razor-pages

You have a separate style sheet being applied in the first example as seen with the source link of  "CoursePro...." instead of it resolving the class from "_buttons.scss". It could be an isolated css file nested under the page. Otherwise you can do a search for "btn-primary" in *.CSS & *.SCSS files to locate any custom implementation, then work back to how/where this stylesheet is being referenced in your first page example.

@PeterB, StevePy thank you both, found .css file and resolve tthe problem. I can't remember how I changed anything in this file, could it be that it somehow generated the styles for the tags itself or is that not possible?
